# Can I unregister a content handler added with nsIWebContentHandlerRegistrar.registerContentHandler()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, feed

For a bootstrapped add-on I am creating, I am registering a content handler, for feeds, in `startup()` with:

```js
const registrar = Cc[ '@mozilla.org/embeddor.implemented/web-content-handler-registrar;1' ].getService( Ci.nsIWebContentHandlerRegistrar );
registrar.registerContentHandler( 'application/vnd.mozilla.maybe.feed',
                                  myUri,
                                  myName,
                                  null );
```

This all works as expected.

However, at `shutdown()` I want to unregister this content handler again, because otherwise — with subsequent start-ups — I end up with multiple preference entries like:

```
browser.contentHandlers.types.<n>.*
```

But... there is no `unregisterContentHandler` method in `nsIWebContentHandlerRegistrar`.

I tried a few variations of calling `registerContentHandler` with `null` values, hoping that *that* would do the trick, but that does not work either, unfortunately (results in newly added `browser.contentHandlers.types.<n+1>.*` values).

Then I found an implementation of [`nsIWebContentConverterService`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/WebContentConverter.js), with the method [`removeContentHandler`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/WebContentConverter.js#260), which I thought might do the trick:

```js
const service = Cc[ '@mozilla.org/embeddor.implemented/web-content-handler-registrar;1' ].getService( Ci.nsIWebContentConverterService );
service.removeContentHandler( 'application/vnd.mozilla.maybe.feed',
                              myUri );
```

However, that doesn't do anything in my case, either.

Is there a way to unregister a content handler in an elegant manner? Or do I need to do it manually, by removing mentioned preference entries and possibly other related "stuff"?

If the latter is applicable, what "stuff" do I need to consider removing for a thoroughly clean removal of my content handler?

**edit:**
There was a misunderstanding on my part. I didn't have a clear understanding yet of what adding/removing a Web Feed content handler actually did.

I was only looking at the auto-generated list that you see when you view an rss feed in your browser, if you haven't selected a default rss viewer yet. *That* list is generated by the `browser.contentHandlers.types.<n>.*` entries.

But the content handler is also added to the *Edit -> Preferences -> Applications -> Web Feed* action list. And on inspecting *that* list, it turns out the content handler was removed just fine upon calling `nsIWebContentConverterService.removeContentHandler()`. It's just that that method does not remove the preferences added by `nsIWebContentHandlerRegistrar.registerContentHander()`.

As it turns out, `nsIWebContentConverterService` actually inherits `nsIWebContentHandlerRegistrar`, so it defines both `registerContentHander()` *and* `removeContentHandler()`.

The object that implements `nsIWebContentConverterService` is [`WebContentConverterRegistrar`](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/WebContentConverter.js#140), and on inspecting the methods `registerContentHander()` *and* `removeContentHandler()` I saw that `removeContentHandler()` does not remove the preferences added by `registerContentHander()`, so I [filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145832) about this, as I believe this could be considered a bug.

Comment: This might help, theres a section on how to unregister protocol handlers which might be similar: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/2faaac70c62bc13e7773

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks! Unfortunately there was a misunderstanding on my part: `removeContentHandler()` *does* actually remove the content handler, just not the preferences added with it in `registerContentHandler()`, so I filed [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145832) (at least, I believe it could be considered a bug).